# Moving characters to the end of line (EOL) with SED

Tags: linux, unix, bash, shell, sed

Any time the word “The” appears at the beginning of a line, I want to move it to the end of the line and capitalize the new first word in the line.  For example, “The heaven” becomes “Heaven the”. I'm trying to test this out for my Library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
sed 's/^The \(.*\)/\u\1 the/'
```

Comment: Hm, that moves 'the' to the end of the line, but it doesn't capitalize the first letter of each word at the beginning of the line. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: It does. Look at the `\u`.

Answer (score 2):

In case your `sed` doesn't have `\u`:

```
awk '$1 ~ "^The" {the=tolower($1); $1=""; char=toupper(substr($0,2,1)); rest=substr($0,3); print char rest, the}' inputfile
```

Assigning a null to `$` leaves the field separator (a space) in place. The first `substr()` starts at character 2 to skip that space. The comma near the end prints the `OFS` (output field separator which defaults to a space).